# Iterate & Search for a string in child items

Tags: powershell

I am trying to build a PowerShell script that iterates through a list of files and searches and removes a match, not having much luck, here is my script

```
$path = "D:\Test\"
$filter =  "*.txt"
$files = Get-ChildItem -path $path -filter $filter

foreach ($item in $files)
{
    $search = Get-content -path $path$item
    $search| select-string -pattern "T|"
}
```

At the moment the script is just returning the whole content of the file and not the select string.

Basically each file in the folder will have a trailer record at the end i.e. `T|1410` I need to iterate through all the files and delete the last line, some of these files will be 200mb+ can someone guide me please.

I've edited my script and now I am using the following method.

```
$path = "D:\Test\"
$filter =  "*.txt"
$files = Get-ChildItem -path $path -filter $filter

foreach ($item in $files)

{
            $search = Get-content $path$item
            ($search)| ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 'T\|[0-9]*', '' } | Set-Content $path$item
}
```

**I am using Powershell v.2**

**However, this is adding a new empty line to my end of file as well as leaving the replace empty, how can I avoid this as well as starting the search from the bottom**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> -pattern "T|"
> ```

That pattern matches a "T" or nothing. But there is nothing between every pair of characters in any string. To avoid the usual regular expression handling of `|` as an alternates separator, use a backslash to match a literal `|`:

```
-pattern "T\|"
```

Alternately, use `Select-String`'s `-SimpleMatch` switch to stop the argument to `-Pattern` being treated as a regular expression.

Comment: If he continues using a RegEx match, and he joined his array with new line characters 'r'n (change the single quotes to backticks, since comments and backticks are not friends) before doing the replace, and changed his replace to be `'T\|[0-9]*\s*$'` it would replace the trailing record along with any whitespace, including new lines, which should take care of his current issue.

Answer (score 2):

As Richard mentioned, you have to escape the `|` character.

You could also use the [regex::escape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx) function for that:

```
[regex]::Escape("T|")
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from escaping the characters the other option you have available is the `-SimpleMatch` switch. From [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx)

> Uses a simple match rather than a regular expression match. In a simple match, Select-String searches the input for the text in the Pattern parameter. It does not interpret the value of the Pattern parameter as a regular expression statement.

If you don't want to have to worry about escaping the characters and are not using regex this would be the way to go.

```
$search | select-string -pattern "T|" -SimpleMatch
```